# Get time from Unix milliseconds timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, type-conversion

My MySQL version is 5.6; it has a [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function. But it works for timestamps with 10 digits: 1447430881.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1447430881);
        -> '2015-11-13 10:08:01'
```

Now I want to get the date from a milliseconds timestamp (e.g. 1556948248000), so using `FROM_UNIXTIME` I got `NULL`.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1556948248000);
        -> NULL
```

Isn't there a `FROM_UNIXMILLITIME` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Universal solution (for `datetime >= '2001-09-09 04:46:40'` - see comments).

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(@time * POWER(10, 9 - FLOOR(LOG10(@time))));
```

`@time` variable contains unix timestamp (any accuracy). For example, when it is `1556948248123`, it is normalized to `1556948248.123` by the FROM_UNIXTIME's argument expression, and the result will be `2015-11-13 19:08:01.123000`. The same result will be obtained when the variable is `1556948248.123` or, for example, `1.556948248123`.

This variable is a placeholder - it can be fieldname or number literal.

You may create your own UDF if needed:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_from_unixtime(arg DECIMAL(65, 30))
RETURNS DATETIME(6)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
RETURN FROM_UNIXTIME(arg * POWER(10, 9 - FLOOR(LOG10(arg))));
```

Comment: Not quite universal.  It fails before 2001-09-08 18:46:40.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it fails, when timestamp is less than `'2001-09-09 04:46:40'`. But no way to distinguish does the timestamp is too ancient or it is so "over-normalized".

Answer (score 1):

[Just tested with MySQL version 5.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8a6a9bb6380033216eb378e498d77418)

```
5.6.35-80.0-log
```

Adding milliseconds as the fractional part will work just fine

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1447430881.123);
```

Will result in

```
2015-11-13 16:08:01.123
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This simple math worked for me:
`select ts, from_unixtime(ts / 1000) from tbl;`